# failed to execute script example_script_name; no such file or directory;

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, exe

I tried converting my python file to exe using pyinstaller
It is getting converted to exe but fails to start
The error says:[no such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1PFX.png)
referring to the image used in my script
How to embed an image(s) to my exe?

Comment: I guess you should keep all the images at the path which you have given in your `python` application.

Comment: how you are converting python file to exe?

Comment: all the images are already in the same folder as that of the script

Comment: @TusharNiras using **pyinstaller**

Comment: @Rendevou I mean are your trying this? `pyinstaller /path/to/yourscript.py` If yes, also check execute permission to file.

Comment: @TusharNiras the issue with execution is clearly given in the error page that i have attached. Please have a look. I want to know why my image file is not getting embedded with exe. I am getting images in the following manner 'gp = Image.open(r'GP.jpg').resize((300, 330),Image.ANTIALIAS)'

Comment: Is the below solution working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using absolute path?

```
import os.path
im = Image.open(os.path.abspath('GP.jpg'))
```